# Issue with the single quote with passing a string to the javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm using a custom tag to get the title of a field from a template. In this case, there's a field "customerEmailTitle" that has the string "Riot Team's Email". I'm passing it within the javascript function checkEmailAddress (as seen below):

```
<input onBlur="checkEmailAddress(this, 'The input is an invalid <getName:getField fieldKey="customerEmailTitle"/> address')" />
```

But the single quote in Riot Team's Email seems to be throwing the page off and won't process the javascript properly. I tried escaping the single quotes and the double quotes in the input tag but nothing seems to be working. Anyone has a better idea as to how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It may helpful for you. As you can set the data/string on data attribute of input element.

```
<html>
<body>
<input data-message="'The input is an invalid <getName:getField fieldKey='customerEmailTitle'/> address')" onblur="checkEmailAddress(this)" type="text" />

</body>

<script>
    function checkEmailAddress(elm){
        alert(elm.dataset['message']);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```